# javascript function doesn't show html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, html-table

I tried to make a html table using java script

```
function CreateTable(data) {
  alert(data);
  /*
  1 - Loop Through Array & Access each value
  2 - Create Table Rows & append to table
  */
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data[i].Billing_Count}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].Flag_Type}</td>
</tr>
            `
    var table = $("#table-body")
    table.append(row)
  }
}
```

and my html :

```
<div id="chartdiv">
  <table id="our-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>میزان مصرف</th>
        <th>نوع مشترک</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

i used the `alert()` in my js to see if my data can be read, and it was ok. but still there were no result in my web page and the table-body's div.
I also have no specific error

Comment: Typo: You're missing the `#` in `$("#table-body")`

Comment: I fixed it but still no table is shown...

Comment: Do you see the table contents if you look in the Elements tab of DevTools?

Comment: hmmm... no!! it doesn't even show the divs :(

Comment: Then your problem is not with this code.

Comment: i wanted this to display when i click on a selection box. it shows the table first, but when i call that function then there will be none

Comment: Something else must be removing the table.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: there are too many codes related to it... cuz it gets value from multiple selection boxes

Comment: If you can't post the code that's actually causing the problem, then you're on your own. I suggest you set a breakpoint on subtree modification, then the code will stop and show you where it's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues in your code:

1. You are missing the id symbol (`#`) in the selector, should be `$("#table-body")`.
2. You have to close the row with `</tr>`.

Comment: yeah, I fixed this. but there's still nothing to display

Comment: @Depie, your code does not show how you are calling the function!!!

Comment: i just challed it with CreateTable(data); in another js file and it's ok. it calls it

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `#` in your selector.

`$("#table-body")` or `document.querySelector("#table-body")` will fix it.

https://codepen.io/Choppy/pen/eYzLMgL

Answer (score 0):

**issue 1: -** while creating the row, you missed out the end `tr` tag

**issue 2: -** $("table-body") - `#` symbol was missing.

```js
function CreateTable(data){
    /*
    1 - Loop Through Array & Access each value
    2 - Create Table Rows & append to table
    */
    for (var i in data){
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data[i].Billing_Count}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].Flag_Type}</td> </tr>
            `
    var table = $("#table-body");
    table.append(row)
    }

    }

    const data = [{Billing_Count: 'Count1', Flag_Type: 'Flap1'},
                  {Billing_Count: 'Count2', Flag_Type: 'Flap2'},
                  {Billing_Count: 'Count2', Flag_Type: 'Flap2'}]
    CreateTable(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chartdiv">
                    <table id="our-table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>میزان مصرف</th>
                          <th>نوع مشترک</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="table-body">
                   
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: i read the data from server, when i get an alert from it, shows my data but I still have nothing such as a table on my page